# Determine which target angular application is running on

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I don't see any info about this on stackoverflow or angular website so I decided to ask. How to determine if application is running with `--target=production` or `--target=development`. Currently I know how to determine environment but I have no idea how to determine target.

I need to check this in my `main.ts` file so I can call method `enableProdMode()`. Currently I'm using ugly solution and I put boolean property in my environment file called `production` so I can check this using:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    enableProdMode();
}
```

But I don't like this solution because the environment decide about target mode. If I execute:

`ng serve --target=development --environment=ENV_NAME`

Then it depends completely on env if `enableProdMode()` will be called or not. If I use for this purpose [`isDevMode`](https://angular.io/api/core/isDevMode) then it wont work because it depends on [`enableProdMode`](https://angular.io/api/core/enableProdMode). Currently I need to have a lot of environments and for each environments I need to have two files (for each target) which I think is very redundant.

How to check real target?

Comment: Why do you need separate files depending on the target?

Comment: I have one application but it works in two modes. Lets call it `A` and `B`. I have different values for common set of properties for each mode in `env-A.ts` and in `env-B.ts` files. Now I would like to build mode A or B for production and development. So I need to add another env files like `env-A.dev.ts`, `env-A.prod.ts`, `env-B.dev.ts`, `env-B-prod.ts`. In `env-A*` files I have all properties the same instead of production variable. Why target parameter doesn't control this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `target` in angular-cli is just used to control wether it's production or dev build, with respect to optimization (css, code,...)

Given your scenario, I think that config files for A or B modes should be in a separate config file that you can retrieve at runtime.  In your normal `environment.[name].ts` files (so dev/.../prod), you can have a `mode` setting (A or B) that you can use to determine which confi to fetch

Comment: Thanks. Currently I used angular-cli feature to setup more than one apps in one project. Then during ng serve or ng build I only need to specify --app parameter